# Installing Mongodb From Command Promp(Error: WirdTiger is not available with this build of mongod )

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, mean-stack

[I have problem while installing Mongod on my machine. Will any buddy explain what is WirdTiger and how i will fix this issue?. I had installed mongodb on my computer. I had already made folder Data\db but its not installing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fiHA.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's the default storage engine for mongodb, it is possible you're experiencing a version error. You could try running this command in your Mongo/bin/.

```
    mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath [your-path]
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If this answer has answered your question could you so kindly mark it as accepted?